# UITableViewController Background Color

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, ios7

I'm struggling getting the color behind the UITableView to be the gray I want.  The background of the UITableView seems to be working fine, but the area behind it still remains white?

[image]

here is the end of my view.  There is only one cell in this and its not a cropped image.  I'm using a UITableViewController so I've set the background of the table view and all the cells.  But still the area above (when you pull to refresh) and the area below are white.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have to set the gray you want as the background color of the UITableViewCell.

Set the backgroundColor property:

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
```

Note that the backgroundColor must be set in the tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method.

Comment: That gives me the same results I already have.  The problem area i have is below the table.  In the picture above there is only one cell and everything below it is white.  I'm trying to get that white gray.

Comment: If your table has only one cell, the table should end just after that cell, so the white space below is the background of the view. Try setting: `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor]` in your `viewDidLoad`. You can do it also via the .xib files.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to judge with whatever you have mentioned in your question. If the background color of tableView is working fine as per your expectation then could you please try setting clear color for your cells for them to use tableView's color. I hope this should work and if not then could you please share the code of your view controller for us to have a closure look on whats happening.

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Comment: I've tried adjusting the cell background colors without success.  I've updated my question to help clarify my issue.  Thanks.

Comment: Did you set the clearColor for cell background? If so then check the frame of your tableView.